# Is there any reason why ext4 device drivers cannot be updated to allow online resize (reduce AND extend)?

Tags: ext4, resize2fs

Question says it all really. I am a little baffled why ext4 doesn't already provide the ability for a partition to be resized online. Can anyone help me to understand why this does not exist please? Is it something that no one is asking for, or is it that no one has had time to develop this functionality? Is there somewhere where I can help to create this functionality? Or request it? Or to contribute towards a bounty?

Comment: Ext4 does allow online resizing, at least when expanding...

Answer (score 1):

There are, you just have to look for them; Btrfs, etc

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Resize_capabilities